Пропал перевод в "Статистика проверяющего" в очереди проверок предлагаемых правок


Ох, 108 строк

@αλεχολυτ ого, какой-то глюк похоже

Скорее всего просто точку в конце добавили или запятую где-то. Поэтому строки и слетели. Можно поисследовать в связки с transifex на досуге.

Вот тут собака порылась
